# Function mt_rand maximum range of values?

Tags: php, function, random

Is there a maximum range of values passed in `mt_rand()` function? Is there a maximum 'top' number for it?

Do said limitations depend on platform?

Does `mt_rand()`'s speed depend on the range passed in?

In other words, would `mt_rand(0,100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)` work?

Sorry for few questions in one.

Comment: I think the max number is based on your system 32 bit or 64 bit

Comment: answers below state that it's not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [returns a pseudo-random value between 0 and mt_getrandmax()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Why don't you just call `mt_getrandmax` and find out? [A commenter writes:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-getrandmax.php#105347)

> On both 32 and 64-bit systems (OS X and Linux), mt_getrandmax() returns 2147483647 for me, i.e. ~2^31.

Comment: Thank you, that answers it. How about the speed dependency, do you have any info on that

Answer (score 1):

Yes, yes, I would imagine so, and probably not. [Take a look at the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) before getting too far into this; the maximum value it can return is based on the system running the script. Take a look at [mt_getrandmax() for more information](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-getrandmax.php), but from what I have read, something like 2147483647 (~2^31) is the max on a 32 and 64 bit system, however I have never tested it personally.